# Taking input in integer /string and store it in array

Tags: java

how would I take `Integer` user input such that `502` and store it in the form of array ,like `arr[0]=5`, `arr[1]=0,arr[2]=2` and access it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [`Integer.toString()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString()) to transform your `Integer` into a `String` and then use [`String.toCharArray()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) that will transform your `String` into a `char[]`.

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare your scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Waits the user to input a value in the console
        Integer integer = sc.nextInt();

        // Close your scanner
        sc.close();

        // Put your string into a char array
        char[] array = integer.toString().toCharArray();

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

input : `502`

output : `[5, 0, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] charArray = String.valueOf(inputInt).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
char[] chars = String.valueOf(520).toCharArray(); // it is the cahr array
// if you want to convert it integer array you can it as below
int[] array = new int[chars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = chars[i];
}
System.out.println("array = " + Arrays.toString(chars));
```

And it is the output:

```
array = [5, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyClass {

    public static int[] toArray(String input) {
        // 1) check if the input is a numeric input
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input \"" + input + "\" is not an integer", e);
        }

        // 2) get the separate digit characters of the input
        char[] characters = input.toCharArray();
        // 3) initialize the array where we put the result
        int[] result = new int[characters.length];
        // 4) for every digit character
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
            // 4.1) convert it to the represented digit as int
            result[i] = characters[i] - '0';
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Downvoters please leave a comment about what's wrong so I can improve and/or learn something new